# Computation Inside Model Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, model

Good day everyone. I just wanna know if it's possible to do computations inside a model, disregarding the database? If it is, how will I do it? If not, can someone explain? Thanks.

Example:

```
var $monthly = '';
var $annually = '';
var $quarterly = '';
var $semiannual = '';

function computation($price, $quantity){
    $this->monthly = $price * $quantity;
    $this->annually = $price * $quantity * 12;
    $this->quarterly = $price * $quantity * 3;
    $this->semiannual = $price * $quantity * 6;
}
```

Comment: The models are just regular classes. You can do whatever you want inside them.

Comment: @xbonez: So how can I do computations inside them? Sorry, I only use models for database purposes so I don't know how to do it.

Comment: See answer for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Models are just regular classes - you write methods to do your calculation and then call them from the controllers as needed. See example below:

```
class Circle extends CI_Model {
  public function area($rad) {
     return 3.14 * $rad * $rad;
  }
}

class CircleCtrl extends CI_Controller {
  public function calc_area() {
    $this->load->model('Circle');
    $area = $this->circle->area(10);
  }
}
```